# Jquery Each index stays at 0

Tags: jquery

I have a part in my script where it loops through the number of elements in a list, and grabs the information then puts it into a different div.  For some reason the first each loop will not count up on its index. Ive tried several different ways to do this, but it seems none are working.

here is the script:

```
//check each Item for a List
if ($(obj).has('> ul')) {

    // Second Level Lists
    $(obj).find('> ul').each(function (index, obj) {

        // Create Second Level Divs
        baseElement.append(
            '<div class="level" id=' + index +
            ' style="color:' + settings.startColor + ';background:' +
            settings.startBg +';font-size:' + settings.baseFont +
            'px;position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>'
        );

        // Second Level List Items
        $(obj).find('> li').each(function (i, obj) {
            $('.level#2').append(
                "<span>" +
                $(obj).find('>:first-child').text() +
                "</span>"
            );
        });
    });

}
```

I need to make it so it counts up and names each of the created div's a number up from the last... Ive picked my brain and dont know what could be going wrong.

Comment: can use `.children('ul')` instead of `.find('> ul')`?

Comment: As an aside, `id=' + index + '` isn't a valid HTML id (Cannot start with a number). You'e also re-defining `obj` in that scope (a couple times).

Comment: @BradChristie: It's valid in HTML5.

Comment: @Blender: orly? Hrm, learn something new. interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your inner loop only appends to `.level#2`, which probably isn't what you want. If I'm reading your question correctly, this should work:

```
$(obj).children('ul').each(function(index) {
    var $parent = $('<div>', {
        'class': 'level',
        id: index,
        css: {
            color: settings.startColor,
            background: settings.startBg,
            fontSize: settings.baseFont + 'px',
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
        }
    }).appendTo(baseElement);

    $(this).children('li').each(function() {
        $('<span>', {
            text: $(this).children().first().text()
        }).appendTo($parent);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for just beautiful code. It's a love/hate thing, but I love the object parameter for initializing jQuery objects. ;p

Comment: @BradChristie: I just looked at the documentation for it and apparently it takes *any* method as a property, so you could also do `$('<span>', {text: 'foo', empty: true}).appendTo('body');` and the span will get emptied out. It's pretty cool.

Comment: so why isn't `appendTo: baseElement` in that ctor then (since what you say [works](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L113-L125))? ;p

Comment: @BradChristie that would be way too hard core IMO

Comment: @BradChristie: I don't know if I'd ever use it, but it does look interesting: http://jsfiddle.net/R2dDu/1/